# hot to best return Hubspot errors with php / jquery

Tags: php, laravel, exception, hubspot-api

Hubspot is returning errors i.e. for an exiting contact as a string looking something like this (dump) when an exception occurs:

> Client error: 'POST [https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact?hapikey=***'](https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact?hapikey=***%27) resulted in a '409 Conflict' response:
> {"message":"Contact already exists","identityProfile":{"vid":851,"identity":[{"value":"xxx.xxx@xxx.com"," (truncated...)

What is the best way to access the values of "message" and "vid" in PHP or jQuery/Javascript?

here's the php (in a livewire component but could easily be a controller etc. as well)  code that makes the call:

```
try {
    $contact = Hubspot::contacts()->create([
        [ 'property' => 'email', 'value' => $this->email ],
        [ 'property' => 'firstname',    'value' => $this->firstname ],
        [ 'property' => 'lastname',     'value' => $this->lastname ],
        [ 'property' => 'phone',        'value' => $this->phone ],
        [ 'property' => 'gender',       'value' => $this->gender],
    ]);

    session([ 'hubspot_vid' => $contact->vid ]);
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('debug', 'Contact Created on Hubspot with the ID of: ' . $contact->vid);

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

and this is how I (for the moment) process the response on the client side:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('debug', event => {
        console.log('Debug Msg.: ' + event.detail);
    })
</script>
```

I would love to be able to do something like:

```
$response = $e->getMessage(); // still the whole string returned?!
$message  = $response->message (or $response['message']) // returns: "Contact already exists" only
$id       = $response->vid (or $response['vid']) // returns: "851" only 
.
.
```

you'll get the idea.

Comment: Well there is a bit in there that looks like JSON and would be easy to use, Do you get that part in a response variable all on its own or is it always poluted with the error message part

Comment: it returns the whole thing as a string and hell, yes ... a JSON object would do the trick but I wasn't able to figure out if this is even an option.

I would be okay to be able to "exctract" only the part of that string that looks like JSON with PHP but all the explode(), strpos() and substr() ... that just doesn't look reliable and by far to complex.
to answer your question - long story short: I get that part from the "catch" Exception $e as one string - nothing else ... just one string

Comment: So out of interest what is in `$contact` when you are in an error situation?

Comment: Undefined variable $contact - so, nothing ;)

Comment: Logic dictates that - If you get returned a JSONString in the error message it should  also be available somewhere usable! I assume you are paying for access to this service so I suggest you ask this question of their tech support